# Continue after failed assertion

Tags: automated-tests, soapui

Once an assertion fails( typically API response ), the remaining test steps in a test case do not get executed. How do I get SoapUI to continue on and complete the rest of the test steps?
I am also looking for a way to retry that step again with the same set of data. If not possible, skip that and proceed to next set of items. Any idea on this ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1- Double click on the test case (not test step)

look at the provided picture and find the one shown below:

[image]

Comment: Just to be clarify the steps: (1) double click the Test Case, (2) click the Set Options icon (the picture shown above will display), (3) uncheck the Fail on error check box, (4) click the OK button to save the change.

Answer (score 13):

To continue tests executing after failed test step you need disable "Fail on error" option in TestCase options.

To control test execution flow you can use "Conditional Goto" test step (the easiest way) or  "Groovy script" test step if you need more complex logic.

Detailed instructions here: http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/controlling-flow.html

Answer (score 1):

**In Ready Api (Soapui pro) right click on Test Case and click on Option.**

[image]

Abort test if an error occurs (Disable)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In SOAPUI free version you can go to the test case and click on the gear or settings icon which opens up a pop up and uncheck the option "Abort test if error occurs"[image: option to continue execution on error in test step]