# SOAP UI Script assertion

Tags: soapui, assert

i need to validate many assertions in same script assertion. But when any one of assert fails, runner stops there itself and control passed to next step. Below is my case

```
assert (1 ==1);
log.info "1";
assert (1 == 2);
log.info "2";
assert (1 ==3);
log.info "3";
```

When i execute the above, 2nd assertion fails and third assertion did not executed at all. Is there is any way to validate all assertions.

Comment: Does [disabling "fail on error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16341547/continue-after-failed-assertion) solve the problem?

Comment: in my case, I want to run the codes available after a failed assertion. "Fail on error" option works on step level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could work:

```
java.util.ArrayList<String> failedAssertions = new java.util.ArrayList<String>()
def allAssertionsPassed = true
if (!1==1) {
    failedAssertions.add("1==1")
    allAssertionsPassed = false
}
if (!1==2) {
    failedAssertions.add("1==2")
    allAssertionsPassed = false
}
if (!1==3) {
    failedAssertions.add("1==3")
    allAssertionsPassed = false
}

if (!allAssertionsPassed ) {
    log.info "Failed assertions:"
    for (def s : failedAssertions) {
        log.info s
    }
}
assert(allAssertionsPassed)
```

Comment: You can probably improve on this, by creating an ArrayList of the assertions themselves as strings, and then evaluate and execute these in a loop. You can then reuse the same ArrayList when logging.

Answer (score 1):

As usual, Steen has submitted a good answer (up-voted).

In my test suites, I have some tests where I want SoapUI to stop where there is a fail (e.g. assert).  I have other tests where I want the test to continue where there is fail.  To implement this, I usually have some Groovy script to do the result check.  E.g. Pass/Fail.  I then use a data-sink step to record each test's details with the result.  I can then view the results in Excel for test reporting.